# Multilingual characters in javascript, php, html, and mysql queries

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm creating a website currently where one of the features is allowing the user to edit any text in a `contenteditable` `div` that they would like. This text would later be posted in `json` format by `jQuery` to a `PHP` script which either inserts or updates the record in the mysql database.

Everything is working fine in the English alphabet. But there will be multilingual users that will use the site. are there any languages that I would need to have special support for in any part of the process I described above?

The main thing that I am worried about is the database collation/field type.

I have tried to test this as well as possible but I was wondering if anyone has had any problems with characters from other languages. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While creating database set the character set to utf-8. example

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name
CHARACTER SET utf8
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci
DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Use `mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8")` before updating data to/from MySQL

Use header`header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8') ;`

or meta tags like

`<meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

If you are using ajax to update the content, there shouldn't be any issues as W3C states that ajax data charset is always utf-8

Answer (score 0):

The UTF8 charset is one of the best (and the most used) for international characters and I also advise you to use `SET NAMES utf8` for MySQL and to prefer header() to the meta-tag.